# how would i use php to display multiple buttons on a web page (they are going to control a raspberry pi)

Tags: python, linux, raspberry-pi, composer-php

i am creating a home automation system, i am using my raspberry pi as a web server to control the gpio ports, p have used some code to turn on the gpio ports. what i want to do is have different php buttons that run different python scripts in turn they turn on different ports. i know lots about python but very little about php and html.

this is all the code i have so far for turning on a gpio port through php

```
 <html>
 <head>
 <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width" />
 <title>LED Control</title>
 </head>
         <body>
         LED Control:
         <form method="get" action="gpio.php">
                 <input type="submit" value="ON" name="on">
                 <input type="submit" value="OFF" name="off">
     </form>
     <?php
     $setmode17 = shell_exec("/usr/local/bin/gpio -g mode 17 out");
     if(isset($_GET['on'])){
             $gpio_on = shell_exec("/usr/local/bin/gpio -g write 17 1");
             echo "LED is on";
     }
     else if(isset($_GET['off'])){
             $gpio_off = shell_exec("/usr/local/bin/gpio -g write 17 0");
             echo "LED is off";
     }
     ?>
     </body>
```

i also wont to controle an 8 channel relay, meaning i will need 8 buttons. i have made up some basic code for running the raspberry pi scripts, i dont know hot to put it all together though.

```
<?php

if (isset($_POST['LightON']))
{
exec("sudo python /home/pi/lighton.py");
}
if (isset($_POST['LightOFF']))
{
exec("sudo python /home/pi/lightoff.py");
}
?>
```

Thanks,
Sam
    i am aware the variable names are different

Comment: I'd use jquery and ajax

Comment: If you are fluent with python, they have a library to control the gpio stuff. Build the website with flask or django perhaps

Comment: You might also want to tag your question with raspberry pi -- you might draw more responses

Answer (score 0):

One solution would be to add all your html into a php file, add all your php code on top of that and run it in your browser. This assuming that www-data user have correct permissions on your file systems to execute the python scripts.

Example:

```
<?php

if (isset($_POST['on']))
{
exec("sudo python /home/pi/lighton.py");
}
if (isset($_POST['off']))
{
exec("sudo python /home/pi/lightoff.py");
}
?>

<html>
 <head>
 <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width" />
 <title>LED Control</title>
 </head>
 <body>
     LED Control:
     <form method="POST" >
          <input type="submit" value="ON" name="on">
          <input type="submit" value="OFF" name="off">
     </form>
 </body>
</html>
```

Alternatively if you know Python well, configure ModPython on Apache and use a py file as your server side script with JQuery on the client side to pass the button presses.